# Module.exports vs plain json for config files

Tags: json, node.js, config

I see multiple ways to create config files in Node.js. One uses module.exports in js file, one just use plain json object.

```
// config1.js
module.exports = {
  config_1: "value 1",
  config_2: "value 2"
}
```

```
// config2.json
{
  "config_1": "value 1",
  "config_2": "value 2"
}
```

Is there any advantages of using module.exports in config file? What are the differences?

Comment: the only real difference is that you can't add comments in json files. you may be interested in using an rc file if you want a json file with comments.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I noticed that module.exports will be only valid in *.js file and for json object only valid in *.json file. I could put comment using module.exports in *.js file.

Comment: Another important note is that a actual .json file has more strict syntax, for example keys have to be wrapped in double quotes, you can't have a comma at the end of an array of items, etc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## javascript CommonJS Module

- comments
- conditionals
- loops and such to populate defaults
- code to change config based on NODE_ENV or similar
- code to look for external files for SSL keys, API credentials, etc
- easier to have fallbacks and defaults

## JSON file

- easy to parse and update with external tools
- compatible with pretty much every programming language out there
- pure data that can be loaded without being executed
- easy to pretty print
- JSON could start as the basis and all the code items described above about CommonJS module could live in a config.js module that reads config.json as it's starting point

So I always start with a commonjs module for the convenience, but keep any logic in there simple. If your config.js has bugs and needs tests, it's probably too complicated. KISS. If I know for a fact other things are going to want poke around in my config, I'll use a JSON file.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks @jonathan-ong, looks like config.js (**NOT JSON file**) works as expected and I could put some comments.

```
module.exports = {

  // Development Environment

  development: {
    database: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      login: 'dev',
      password: 'dev'
    }
  },

  // Production Environment

  production: {
    database: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      login: 'prod',
      password: 'prod'
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

js files have their own perks as @Peter Lyons mentioned. But if I don't have to access external resources for API keys and etc. I would prefer **JSON** for config files.

Simple reason being **I would not have to touch my code for just for the sake of making changes to config files**. I can simply make an API to edit these json files to add,update or remove any configuration key-value pair. Even add whole new config file for a separate environment using an API.

And use config module to consume these configurations