# Best way to invoke code inside a module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, require

From a performance perspective, is there any difference between invoking code by wrapping it in a function and then exporting it:

```
function doSomething () {
    // doing something here
}

module.exports = doSomething();
```

And just requiring it without any exports? like this:

myModule.js

```
// Code doing something
```

file that requires the module:

```
var doSomething = require('./myModule');
```

And if the purpose of the code inside the module is to run just once, do I need to store it in a variable?

Comment: Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687964/best-way-to-invoke-code-inside-a-module-in-nodejs/39689326#39689326) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer and may not read it. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to update them if they need any improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the return value of that function, then you don't have to store it in a variable.

The difference with:

```
function doSomething () {
    // doing something here
}
module.exports = doSomething();
```

and using:

```
var x = require('module');
var y = require('module');
```

vs.

```
function doSomething () {
    // doing something here
}
module.exports = doSomething;
```

and using:

```
var x = require('module')();
var y = require('module')();
```

is that in the first case, the function will be run only once, while in the second case the function will be run twice.

Comment: this is the right answer. I was looking for making a global variable across modules (logger) on all node process lifetime

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that if you just include it without module.exports, then the code will execute immediately but be private to the module.  You can only access the data if you export it somehow, with module.exports.  It can be either a function or a Javascript Object.  Essentially, you can view everything within the module as being completely hidden from everything else in your application.

The only shortcut that I know of is for JSON files.  If you look here: [Module.exports vs plain json for config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476765/module-exports-vs-plain-json-for-config-files), you can see that you can require('file.json') and it will replace the contents of the json file with a Javascript object that you can then use in your application.